# Assigning of unordered_map to pair of objects

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am trying to understand the `unordered_map` assignment, I get the following error: no matching function for call to `std::pair<foo, foo>::pair()`, according to the doc for `unordered_map operator[]`:

> If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new  element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value.

So I am trying to assign an object (from `make_pair`) to this reference, which I am guessing is not allowed.  However with the `pair<int,int>`, it works, then I am wondering if I must declare some other operators for `foo` to make this work.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
  int n;
  foo(int n): n(n) {};
};

int main(){
  unordered_map<int, pair<foo,foo>> m;
  //m[3] = make_pair(foo(1),foo(2));         <--- error here

  unordered_map<int, pair<int,int>> ii;
  ii[3] = make_pair(1,2);
}
```

Comment: Have you read and tried to understand the error message?

Comment: -bitmask, yes I have been staring at it for a while, I would post it here (quite long), if someone can help me decipher it, that would be great.

Comment: Well, it would be useful to be able to help you decipher it, if you'd post it.

Comment: -bitmask, I posted a follow up question, it is not the whole set of errors, let me know if I should add more/less. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60776989/parsing-compilation-error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-stdpair-pair)

Comment: I provided you with a step-by-step guide of how to understand such an error [under that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60778516/430766). Hope it helps.

Comment: -bitmask. It is really super, I think it is so fundamental (anyone can really benefit from it).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `operator []` might have to construct a value object, in your case `std::pair<foo, foo>`.  Since `foo` doesn't have a default constructor, it can't construct the default `std::pair`.

You can either provide a default constructor for `foo` (including adding a default value for `n`), or you'll have to use another method to insert values into `m`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, if I use m.insert(make_pair(key,make_pair(foo(1),foo(2)))), then the default constructor is not invoked, is that correct?  Or are there better ways to do this, thanks!

Comment: You're correct.  You probably want to do some error-checking, but otherwise your suggestion is fine.