# Parsing compilation error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<,>::pair()'

Tags: c++, g++, unordered-map

This is a followup question to [assigning-of-unordered-map-to-pair-of-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767573/assigning-of-unordered-map-to-pair-of-objects).  This is a question about the interpretation of the compiler errors (and not a repeat question, as that question was already fully answered).  I was asked whether I took a look at the errors, and to post the errors so that others might benefit from an understanding.  This is the first error for this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
  int n;
  foo(int n): n(n) {};
  // foo(): n(0) {};
};
int main(){
  unordered_map<int, pair<foo,foo>> m;
  m[3] = make_pair(foo(1),foo(2));
}
```

And here is the first error after compilation (rest omitted for now):

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Weffc++ -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-conversion  pairs.cpp -o ../build/pairs.bin
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/functional:54,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/stdc++.h:71,
                 from pairs.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {int&&}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::pair<foo, foo>]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1657:63:   required from ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {int&&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::pair<foo, foo>]’
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> >, false>]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> >, false>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> >, false> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2093:36:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type* std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::_M_allocate_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _NodeAlloc = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> >, false> >; std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> >, false>]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:736:8:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::operator[](std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::key_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Pair = std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> > >; _Equal = std::equal_to<int>; _H1 = std::hash<int>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type = std::pair<foo, foo>; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::key_type = int]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unordered_map.h:978:20:   required from ‘std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[](std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = std::pair<foo, foo>; _Hash = std::hash<int>; _Pred = std::equal_to<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::pair<foo, foo> > >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::pair<foo, foo>; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’
pairs.cpp:11:6:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1668:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<foo, foo>::pair()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
```

Answer (score 12):

In general try to read these error message backwards.

**1.** Look at the last line (broken up to fit better on the available space)

```
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1668:70: error: no matching function for call
         to ‘std::pair<foo, foo>::pair()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
```

This tells you immediately what's going on: There is a call *somewhere* (we'll have to find out where it originates), to a function that doesn't exist. That function is called

```
std::pair<foo, foo>::pair()
```

This is a constructor of a type from the standard library. Specifically it is a constructor without arguments.

**2.** So let's have a look at the [documentation for pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair). Oddly enough, there seems to be a constructor without arguments there.

**3.** Why doesn't it exist? Let's read on in the documentation:

> 1) Default constructor. Value-initializes both elements of the pair, first and second.
>   This constructor participates in overload resolution **if and only if `std::is_default_constructible_v<first_type>` and
>   `std::is_default_constructible_v<second_type>` are both true**.
>   This constructor is explicit if and only if either first_type or second_type is not implicitly default-constructible.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

**4.** Great let's check the condition, `first_type` and `second_type` are both the type `foo` in this case. Let's examine this type:

```
struct foo {
  int n;
  foo(int n): n(n) {};
  // foo(): n(0) {};
};
```

There is a `foo(int)` constructor for this type, and a commented out `foo()` constructor. There should be an implicit default constructor, right? **[No:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor)**

> **If no user-declared constructors of any kind** are provided for a class
>   type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a
>   default constructor as an inline public member of its class.

We have a `foo(int)`, hence the compiler does not generate `foo()` on its own. Aha, the call fails because indeed the function does not exist.

**5.** Okay, but why is it called in the first place? I don't remember calling such a function. -> Look at the "next" line in your error:

```
pairs.cpp:11:6:   required from here
```

That line (line 11 in pairs.cpp) reads:

```
m[3] = make_pair(foo(1),foo(2));
```

**6.** What does the documentation have to say about the first function called there? [`std::unordered_map<int,std::pair<foo,foo>>::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to
>   key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**.
>   ...
>   When the default allocator is used, this results in the key being copy
>   constructed from key and **the mapped value being [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)**.

**7.** What does value-initialisation mean?

```
T()     (1)     
new T ()    (2)     
Class::Class(...) : member() { ... }    (3)     
T object {};    (4)     (since C++11)
T{}     (5)     (since C++11)
new T {}    (6)     (since C++11)
Class::Class(...) : member{} { ... }    (7)     (since C++11)
```

Remember, `T` here is the `value_type` of your `unordered_map`, which in turn is `pair<foo,foo>`. That looks suspiciously like the call the compiler couldn't find earlier.

**8.** If we want to use `std::unordered_map<K,T>::operator[]`, `T` better be value initialisable, e.g. by providing a `T::T()` constructor. That's where we have to fix it.

**Conclusion**

Read the error meticulously, check out the documentation for stuff you don't already know and follow up on the requirements of the functions you are using. And remember to read the error message backwards to figure out where the error was encountered, and in which of your own files it was triggered. Then examine that line.

Comment: -bitmask thanks so much, I appreciate your guiding step by step.

Answer (score 2):

The library code is trying to default construct a `pair` of `foo` (that's what `std::pair<foo, foo>::pair()` in the last line means). But it can't do that because `foo` doesn't have a default constructor.

All the library templates make certain requirements on the types used to parameterise them. It seems `std::unordered_map` requires a default constructor.

I have a feeling (but I'm not going to look it up) that you could avoid this problem if you didn't use `operator[]` to insert into your map (in other words it's `operator[]` that needs the default constructor). If this is a problem try using `emplace` instead.

```
m.emplace(3, make_pair(foo(1),foo(2)));
```

Comment: Thanks John, yes this was answer given by the linked question.  I am just pondering how you can decipher the last line, when I was first looking at it, I thought, do I need to implement a function std::pair<foo, foo>::pair(), because no matching function was found... it is not clear to me from that error that it is expecting a default constructor for foo.  But there might be other clues that I am overlooking... The point of this question is really how to parse such errors.  (I used m.insert -> works as well as pointed out by Kamil)

Comment: Just follow the diagnostic lines in LIFO order. In the case of this sample, 2nd error from last is the focal hint.

Comment: -Red Wave, just making sure I understand your suggestion, look at the last error, then the one above, etc.  In doing so, I think the one beginning with
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple: In instantiation ...
tells me that it is expecting a constructor for foo with _Args2 = {}, so I had to go all the way to the first line to figure out that it was expecting a zero-parameter constructor.  Is this correct?  It seems you want me to focus on this line instead:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unordered_map.h:978:20:
which is the 2nd error from last (maybe I have my orientations reversed).

Comment: @Red.Wave Think about what a default constructor for pair<foo,foo> would have to do. Obviously it would need to default construct two foo objects, therefore a default constructor for foo is needed.

Comment: I don't defend cryptic diagnostics of C++. Specially when it comes to templates. "Constraint templates" has been one of the oldest and greatest challenges in the committee during last 15yrs or so. The "concept" proposal has had uncountable revisions until it finally made to C++20. It takes some great deal of time till the STL implementations align in that direction. Had the `operator[]` been properly constraint, an early and more readable diagnostic would suffice. Although cascaded error messages is still a long standing story.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unordered_map::operator[]` needs to default construct new element. If you class is not default constructible, you can't use `operator[]` to create new element and then assign to it.

Use `emplace` or `insert` or `insert_or_assign` to insert new element into a map.